# it prompts me to install some gems after I issued 'rails new mysite'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Yes, I can definitely install these dependencies one by one by issuing commands like 'gem install gem-name', but is there a better way to install all these dependencies once for all? I am a rails newbie, thanks :)

Comment: Just add missing gems to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`

Comment: have you tried `bundle install`?

Comment: @basia I thought I should run `bundle install` after `rails new app`, if I run it this way, should I have a Gemfile first?

Comment: @BroiSatse I don't have a `Gemfile` yet, I am following the course from codecademy.com

Comment: Can you actually paste an output you got? Will make our lives much easier :)

Comment: @BroiSatse yeah, sure, here it is http://pastebin.com/W4KQRwf3

Comment: We got that error with `spring` yesterday FYI. We haven't fixed it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
$ rails new my_app --skip-bundle
```

Once installed, you can either populate your `Gemfile` or run `bundle install`, it's your choice.

--

`Rails` won't run without `bundle` being completely up to date. If you're developing, you'll be able to work on the code with the above. If you want to run it, you'll need to use `bundle` after Rails creates the new app.

Comment: it shows no error after I issuing the command you offered me, but after I issued `bundle install`, it still needs me to install the dependencies manually one by one , like [this](http://pastebin.com/Yy2eEmuz)

Comment: This is the normal way dependencies are installed. Installing them "one by one" is the way bundler works ;)

Comment: The problem you have is that the `spring` gem won't install. You need to try `gem uninstall spring` and then `gem install spring` to get it working

Comment: it tells me an error `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3.gem)` . I guess this is caused by China's GFW or something, after I connected my VPN, it works.

Comment: Nice work! You could also try `source http://rubygems.org` at the top of your `Gemfile` to see if that works

Comment: How? Could you please detail it? Should I edit `Gemfile` or something?

Comment: Yes, edit `Gemfile` and at the top it has the "source" for where it looks for gems

Comment: The source is by default `https://` - this can cause problems, you should change it to `source http://rubygems.org`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93915/discussion-between-kenshinji-and-rich-peck).